# React + Ionic Video Recording

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I´m building an app with Ionic and React.

I need to use the phone´s camera to record video but I don´t have a clue how to do this. I´ve been looking around the internet a lot but I cannot find any documentation or tutorial where this is explained. Please remember it needs to be with REACT - not Angular-.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with the `Media Capture Plugin` [Here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media-capture). Ionic has the Cordova or Capacitor plugin that you can work with and with the link there is more documentation for usage.
Most video tutorials are created with Angular, but you can use the same approach.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this short article is far off giving me the proper tools for being able to use the video camera from the phone. And it´s only for images which I´m already handling... So thanks but I´m still looking for something more concrete (if there´s such a thing).

Answer (score 1):

Install the components, plugins

```
npm install cordova-plugin-media-capture
npm install @ionic-native/media-capture
npm install @ionic-native/core
```

Add the imports

```
import {
  MediaCapture,
  MediaFile,
  CaptureVideoOptions,
} from "@ionic-native/media-capture";
```

When using the components in ReactJS, typescript is your friend because it shows you what properties and methods are available on the objects.

In this case what you want is `MediaCapture.captureVideo` which returns a promise that is the media you were looking for or the error that was generated

```js
  const doMediaCapture = async () => {
    let options: CaptureVideoOptions = { limit: 1, duration: 30 };
    let capture:any = await MediaCapture.captureVideo(options);
    console.log((capture[0] as MediaFile).fullPath)
  };
```

Deploying To Device Using Capacitor/CLI

```sh
ionic build
ionic cap sync ios
```

After changes to web code

```sh
ionic cap copy ios
```

After changes to native code/plugins

```
ionic cap sync ios
```

Open up the IDE

```sh
ionic cap open ios
```

Comment: Hi @Aaron, many thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn´t allow me to use cordova  on my project as I´m using capacitor plugins. Do you have an alternatively using only capacitor? Or at least a way to take videos from the phone´s gallery?